# Problemas con contador

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente contador:

- Esta dentro de una tabla en la que se seleccionan alimentos através de un checkbox; De modo que, su función es calcular la suma de las kcal de los alimentos que se seleccionan.
- El problema es que se usa en varias secciones de la misma página y empezaba contando con suma del anterior checkbox. Por ello, intenté mejorarlo con las propiedades de los objetos de javascript, de ahi caloriasT['nombre']. El problema es que me devuelve 'NaN'. ¿Dónde está el error? 
  Muchas gracias!

  ```
  caloriasT={};

  function contador(checkbox,kcal,nombre) {
     var sum=parseFloat(kcal);
     if($(checkbox).is(":checked")){
        caloriasT['nombre']+=sum;
     }else{
        caloriasT['nombre']-=sum;
     }
     $("#"+nombre).html(Math.abs(caloriasT['nombre']).toFixed(2)+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Kcals');
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema principal es que sumas un valor a una variable que todavía no tiene ningún valor definido (no, las variables no se inicializan a `0`, su valor inicial es `undefined`) así que deberías añadir:

```
if (typeof caloriasT[nombre] === 'undefined') {
    caloriasT[nombre] = 0;
}
```

antes de sumar o restar nada. https://jsfiddle.net/s41ndr20/12/

Aparte de eso, estás usando la etiqueta `'nombre'` en vez de el parámetro `nombre` en todas partes, pero eso es oto asunto.

Comment: +1 @SJuan76 Me ganaste por unos segundos, pero en efecto esta es la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias! :)